# Unable to get selected option using JS loop

Tags: javascript, forms, for-loop

I'm getting the selected radio button with a JS for loop, and need to do the same with a select & options dropdown list. I can't seem to figure out exactly what syntax is needed.

See code below

***HTML***

```
    <form name="formeyes">
        <h3>Choose an eye colour</h3>
        Blue <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="Blue" />
        Black <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="Black" />
        Green <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="Green" />
        Grey <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="Grey" />
        Light Brown <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="LightBrown" />
        Dark Brown <input type="radio" name="myradio" value="DarkBrown" />
    </form>


    <div class="select-eyes">
        <h3>Choose an eye colour</h3>
        <select id="formeyes">
            <option type="text" name="myoption" value="eyes">choose eyes</option>
            <option type="text" name="myoption" value="Blue">Blue</option>
            <option type="text" name="myoption" value="Black">Black</option>
            <option type="text" name="myoption" value="Green">Green</option>
            <option type="text" name="myoption" value="Grey">Grey</option>
            <option type="text" name="myoption" value="LightBrown">Light Brown</option>
            <option type="text" name="myoption" value="DarkBrown">Dark Brown</option>
        </select>
    </div>
```

***JS for the radio buttons*** (which correctly console logs the selected value)

```
<script>
var radioEye = ""

var radios = document.forms["formeyes"].elements["myradio"];
for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) { 
    radios[i].onclick = function() {
        radioEye = this.value;
        console.log(radioEye);
        drawAvatar()
    }
}
</script>
```

***JS for the select dropdown*** (in which I want to console log the selected option)

```
var optionEye = ""

var radios = document.getElementById("formeyes").options;

for (var i = 0; i < radios.length; i++) { 
    radios[i].onchange = function() {
        optionEye = this.value
        console.log(optionEye);
        drawAvatar()
    }
}
```

Someone please help.

Comment: Answered , There is no need to use loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things to consider:

A) You don't append the event to the options, but to the select itself.

B) You can use the event variable.

For example:

```
var optionEye = ""

var radios = document.getElementById("formeyes");

radios.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    optionEye = event.target.value;
    console.log(optionEye);
    drawAvatar();
});
```

Event options contain a `target` property, which points to the HTML element, from which you can get the current value.

Answer (score 0):

No you no need to use loop for this just the `onchange()` function *(javascript)* for this call the function on change and get the selected value.

```js
function checkValue() {
  var select_ = document.getElementById("Select").value;
  console.log("You selected: " + select_);
}
```

```html
<select id="Select" onchange="checkValue()">
  <option value="Hello">Hello
  <option value="world">World
</select>
```

Comment: My pleasure, any support from your side give pleasure and happiness to me!